# Django OneToOneField and queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

counter_app:

```
class Logs(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    ...
```

mail_app:

```
class Mail(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    counter = models.OneToOneField(Logs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        c = Logs(name=self.subject, number=0)
        c.save()
        self.counter = c
    
        super(Mail, self).save()
```

How can I get access to the "c" object? How should I connect it with 'counter' field? And also I need it's 'number' field to be used further.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain *what8 you want to achieve. Using the same name for a model is often a *bad* idea.

Comment: *never a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, I've mistaken in second model naming. Now it's correct. Question is correct. And answer is still not found.